# Get-ChildItem using variable for -Include Not Working

Tags: powershell

Current Version of the Question:

I initialize an array $tbd_list as follows:

```
$tbd_list = @()
foreach($i in $tbd) {
    # -- If statement prevents duplicate id's
    if(!($tbd_list -match $i.id)){
        $tbd_list += $i.id
    }
}
```

At this point, if I print $tbd_list I get:

```
"dce50fdd-2298-45db-8aac-fb13a176fe1a*.*"
"79c1538f-09b1-4ed7-b84c-ff1a7934596a*.*"
"60511686-7a87-4352-a781-62e7c04913e5*.*"
"0821f8ee-c1ca-4568-ab68-bb5e30d07268*.*"
"3b9f5da0-fc2d-49e3-a11d-943f5ac2296a*.*"
"ff7720fd-2c0f-43c8-871a-e283f231c823*.*"
```

($tbd_list.GetType().FullName returns System.Object)

I then try to run the following code:

```
Get-ChildItem F:\store_test\ -Recurse -Include $tbd_list
```

But, I get nothing in return.

However, if I manually type this:

```
$tbd_list = "dce50fdd-2298-45db-8aac-fb13a176fe1a*.*", "79c1538f-09b1-4ed7-b84c-ff1a7934596a*.*", "60511686-7a87-4352-a781-62e7c04913e5*.*", "0821f8ee-c1ca-4568-ab68-bb5e30d07268*.*", "3b9f5da0-fc2d-49e3-a11d-943f5ac2296a*.*", "ff7720fd-2c0f-43c8-871a-e283f231c823*.*"
```

At this point, if I print $tbd_list I still get:

```
"dce50fdd-2298-45db-8aac-fb13a176fe1a*.*"
"79c1538f-09b1-4ed7-b84c-ff1a7934596a*.*"
"60511686-7a87-4352-a781-62e7c04913e5*.*"
"0821f8ee-c1ca-4568-ab68-bb5e30d07268*.*"
"3b9f5da0-fc2d-49e3-a11d-943f5ac2296a*.*"
"ff7720fd-2c0f-43c8-871a-e283f231c823*.*"
```

and run the same line ($tbd_list.GetType().FullName still returns System.Object):

```
Get-ChildItem F:\store_test\ -Recurse -Include $tbd_list
```

It works perfectly. Any suggestions?

**Solution**

Both answers below are correct, but I can only choose one.

After making sure the variable was an array, I then had to remove the leading and trailing quotes and the script works. Thanks!

Comment: If `$TBD_List` is an array then that would explain it...Is it an array or a string?

Comment: $tbd_list.GetType().FullName gives System.String

Comment: Try putting `$tbd_list` in double quotes `"$tbd_list"`

Comment: Can you show the code where you define the `$tbd_list` variable?  I think it may have to do with quotes

Comment: It's only defined when it's populated, which I should probably change. Right now it's like this: foreach($i in $tbd) { $tbd_list = "$tbd_list, " + $i.id } ... Where $i.id is something like "ff7720fd-2c0f-43c8-871a-e283f231c823*.*"

Comment: I added the code to the question also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $tbd_list.GetType().FullName gives System.String

While not apparent from your question how you defined the $tbd_list, but it should have been an array and only if it were an array would it work with `Get-ChildItem`'s `Include` option. It wouldn't work in the way you expect if it were a string. Define it properly:

```
$tbd_list = "dce50fdd-2298-45db-8aac-fb13a176fe1a*.", "79c1538f-09b1-4ed7-b84c-ff1a7934596a.*", "dce50fdd-2298-45db-8aac-fb13a176fe1a*.", "79c1538f-09b1-4ed7-b84c-ff1a7934596a.*", "dce50fdd-2298-45db-8aac-fb13a176fe1a*.", "60511686-7a87-4352-a781-62e7c04913e5.*", "0821f8ee-c1ca-4568-ab68-bb5e30d07268*.", "3b9f5da0-fc2d-49e3-a11d-943f5ac2296a.*", "ff7720fd-2c0f-43c8-871a-e283f231c823*.*"
```

Using the above line works for me with `Get-ChildItem`

Update:

This is where you are doing it wrong:

```
$tbd_list = "$tbd_list, " + $i.id
```

It will construct a string.

You will have to initialize `$tbd_list` as an array:

```
$tbd_list = @()
```

and add the items you want to it:

```
$tbd_list += $i.id
```

Comment: I can't get my comments to format. I'm going to show my changes in the question.

Comment: Also, when I do $tbd_list.GetType().FullName after this change I get System.Object. I don't know if that matters, just letting you know.

Comment: If I manually type in $tbd_list = "dce50fdd-2298-45db-8aac-fb13a176fe1a*.*", "79c1538f-09b1-4ed7-b84c-ff1a7934596a*.*" ... etc. and then run the Get-ChildItem line, the code works. But if I set the $tbd_list variable through the code above it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`$i.id` should not include the quote chars. On the command line, they designate a string but when those characters are part of the string stored in a string variable, it's not going to work for you e.g.:

```
9 >  gci t*.txt


    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Keith


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
-a---      4/3/2012  8:54 PM           13 test.txt
-a---    10/20/2011  9:13 AM         2872 trace.txt


10 >  $a = "`"t*.txt`""
11 >  $a
"t*.txt"
12 >  gci * -Include $a
```

Strip off the leading and trailing quotes like so:

```
$tbd_list += $i.id.Trim('"')
```

Comment: Awesome. This with the other suggestions fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern="packages","obj","bin" # needs to be string[]
```

or

```
[string[]] $pattern="packages","obj","bin"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name -Attributes H,!H -Directory -Include $pattern
```